# how do i resolve this error when compiling C code that includes SDL

Tags: c, gcc, sdl-2

when i try to compile the following C code with `gcc -I/SDL2-2.0.20/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include  hsdl.c -L/SDL2-2.0.20/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib` in windows

```
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
int main( int argc, char* args[] ) {
  SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ); //Start SDL
  SDL_Quit(); //Quit SDL
  return 0;
}
```

i get the following errors

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\ccfFajdG.o:hsdl.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\ccfFajdG.o:hsdl.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): in function `main':
C:/_/M/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

i did install SDL headers and library files manually by moving the files to the library and include paths.

Comment: You don't seem to be linking with the SDL libraries.

Comment: Please post how you compile your program. ex: `g++ -o myporg -lsdl` , etc.

Comment: i did compile this `hsdl.c` file by doing  `gcc hsdl.c -o hsdl`

Comment: If you want to use functions from a library, you need to link that library with your code. See linked question

Comment: @ShadowMitia not really, i'm using windows so i have issues using -lsdl or the config info for sdl command (which i don't have as i installed only the headers and libraries manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `gcc` where to find those include files and where to find required libraries for `SDL2`.

Compile your program like this:

```sh
gcc `pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2` ./hsdl.c -o ./hsdl.exe
```

If you haven't installed `SDL2` on msys2 use this command:

```sh
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2
```

If you haven't installed `pkg-config` on msys2 use this command:

```sh
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config
```

Comment: i do not seem to have `sdl2` as a command in msys, how do i install it.

Comment: @ImadHamaidi Just copy all these command and execute them

Comment: when trying to install the SDL library using the command this happens ```File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2-2.0.14-2-any.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] Y
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature))
```

Comment: @ImadHamaidi Use this command 1. `pacman-mirrors --country United_States` 2. `pacman -Syyu`